# KNXnetIP implementation in C#

Tags: c#, knx

I'm developing an application in C# to control my KNX home system. So, i've used the software ETS3Demo, and using the software wireshark could "see" the IP datagrams sent by the ETS3 to the KNX/IP Interface.

I've alredy succeed with the "Connection_Request", "ConnectionState_Request" and "Disconnect_Request", i.e. I send the requests datagram and the KNX/IP Interface responds.

The only request that is giving me headaches is the "Tunnelling_Request". I send the information exactly the same way as I send the previous datagrams, but this one seems not to work.

I send the datagram "byte by byte", as you can see in the following code:

```
byte[] byteToSend1 = { 06, 16, 04, 32, 00, 21, 04 };

string communicationChannel = ComunicationChannelNum.Text;
byte bytesnew = Convert.ToByte(communicationChannel);

byte[] byteToSend2 = { 00, 00, 17, 00, 188, 224, 00, 00, 09, 01, 01, 00, 129 };

writer.WriteBytes(byteToSend1);
writer.WriteByte(bytesnew);
writer.WriteBytes(byteToSend2);
```

I've alredy changed the byte that corresponds to the source address and the group address to a "int" variable, and still doesn't work.

Can someone give me a suggestion or something that I might be doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming here looking up the thread:

You can always use the KNX association Falcon Library that can be downloaded for free and  allows to preform all the operations (run-time and management). It requires you to understand KNX protocol though and isn't the prettiest and cleaner library ever, but works.

here: https://my.knx.org/en/downloads/falcon

Note: May need you to register, but that is for free. [I can't share it here because it would violate the License Agreement. Thanks Mr. Bummi!]

Comment: I am a bit concerned with the license agreement for this product. I think it's fine if you are developing something for yourself, however, if you planning on building a product I recommend very carefully reading their license.

Comment: Knx.Falcon.Sdk is available on nuget.org since a while.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using knx to on/off the light I used [this](http://www.eb-systeme.de/?page_id=479) link to send tunneling request.

Comment: I dont need it any more but thanks any way. I alredy have a Windows 8 App working with a KNX system.

Comment: oh ok :) ... me im still developing in ubuntu :D